# Not able to power on vm because hypervisor is not running, this is VM running in vcenter server

Tags: vmware, hyper-v, hypervisor, windows-server-2019, vcenter

i have vcenter server 5.5, create VM having windows server 2019 os installed.
install Hyper-V Manager but now not able to power on VM tried many things but not able to.
*Already enabled CPU virtualization in VM.
* Hypervisor services are up and running.
* Already added 
vhv.enable = TRUE
hypervisor.cpuid.v0 = FALSE
in VM vmx file.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are looking for
[Nested virtualization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtualization#Nested_virtualization),
which is the ability to run a virtual machine within another, or of
running one hypervisor inside another hypervisor.

By default ESXi doesn’t support nested virtualization.
You need to login to the ESXi host over SSH and reconfigure the config file
located at `/etc/vmware/config` and add a new line containing:

```
vhv.enabled = "TRUE"
```

(On previous ESXi 5.1 it was `vhv.allow = "TRUE"`.)

For more information see the article
[Nested Virtualization on VMware ESXi 5.5](http://tech-trainer.info/nested-virtualization-on-vmware-esxi-5-5/).

Comment: Without adding the entry in the config file in ESXi 6.0, able to power on machine running on vm in vcenter. Needs to test in ESXi 5.5.